# How to control order of doxygen documentation sections?

Tags: documentation, doxygen

I added my documentation as follows: brief description, parameters, and return value get explained in the header, details about the implementation get explained in the source.

However, when I generate the doxygen documentation, instead of having the brief description, the details, then the parameters and lastly the return value, I get these sections in another order: brief, params, return, and details.

I guess this has to do with the order in which doxygen finds the doc comments in the source code. Is there any way I can set the order of the sections to whatever I like, regardless of how the documentation is organized?

Comment: Have you found a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 4):

Generate and then customize the layout.xml file. For more information see [this page on the Doxygen site](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/customize.html).